# Geotiff converter to ecw

Tags: geotiff-tiff, ecw

Does anybody know a converter or how to convert a geotiff file to a ecw file?

Answer (score 2):

It's a proprietary format, you need a paid license.

[ERDAS Imagine / ER Mapper](http://www.hexagongeospatial.com/products/producer-suite/erdas-imagine)

[ERDAS Geocompressor or GDAL with write ECW/JP2 SDK](http://www.hexagongeospatial.com/products/provider-suite/compression-products)

Comment: InfranView does it with ease. Simply copy world file, yourTIF.tfw to yourECW.eww

Comment: I don't recommend it. It uses the buggy deprecated ECW/JP2 v. 3.3 SDK (from 2006) which doesn't support anything other than 8 bit RGB output, i.e no alpha channels, multiband or 16bit data, and is limited to small rasters <= 500MB uncompressed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to FME, you can convert to ECW fairly easily.

Just connect the **[GeoTIFF](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_ReadersWriters/geotiff/geotiff.htm)** reader to an [**ECW Writer**](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_ReadersWriters/ecw/ecw.htm).